# How to add class to existing Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I am very new to Eclipse/Java project. Please help me with some details.

1. I got a Eclipse project from someone. I opened the project in Eclipse. 
   Then I opened a class and it shows:

   ```
   public class APMPage extends Page {
   ```
2. Pressed F3 on Page, I get the Page class. It displays:

   ```
   public abstract class Page extends BasePage
   ```
3. It is not recognizing BasePage. When I press F3 on BasePage, I get nothing.
4. I have BasePage.java in C/Selenium/Framework/BasePage.java. Framework folder has also few other Java files.

I like to add all classes from the framework folder to my existing project.

How can I add that BasePage.java to my Eclipse project, so it can fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Selenium project to your build path. If you right click on you project and select 'properties', it'll take you to the project configuration. Choose build path and add Selenium to the list.

Check this for more details [Java class not recognized within package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697406/java-class-not-recognized-within-package)